# Vite and styled-components - Prop `className` did not match

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, vite, server-side-rendering

I have a React app which is rendered on the server. Recently some of my webpack build process stopped working and I moved to Vite (v 4.4.4). I have two Vite config files (server and client) and when I ran my app I'm getting this: `Prop` className `did not match. Server: "StyledImage-sc-ey4zx9-0 eHxwpP Logo-qePtt kFtWrZ" Client: "StyledImage-sc-ey4zx9-0 isegfO sc-fznyAO bxSNCD"` and my app renders without styles.

Here is my `vite.configServer.ts` file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill';
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill';
import rollupNodePolyFill from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  root: './React',
  build: {
    target: 'modules',
    minify: false,
    cssMinify: false,
    modulePreload: {
      polyfill: true,
    },
    lib: {
      entry: './server.tsx',
      name: 'React',
      fileName: 'server',
    },
    outDir: '../wwwroot/ssr',
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
        // @ts-ignore
        rollupNodePolyFill(),
      ],
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      define: {
        global: 'globalThis',
      },
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          process: true,
          buffer: true
        }),
        NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin()
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    react({
      babel: {
        plugins: [
          ['babel-plugin-styled-components',
          {
            displayName: true,
            fileName: false,
          }]
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
  ssr: {
    noExternal: ['suneditor', 'suneditor-react', 'styled-components', '@emotion/*', 'next', '@babel/*', 'react-to-pdf'],
  },
  resolve: {
    // replaces node default with pylifilled version
    alias: {
      util: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util',
      sys: 'util',
      events: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/events',
      stream: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/stream',
      // path: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/path',
      querystring: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/qs',
      punycode: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/punycode',
      // url: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/url',
      string_decoder: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/string-decoder',
      http: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http',
      https: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http',
      os: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/os',
      assert: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/assert',
      constants: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/constants',
      _stream_duplex: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/duplex',
      _stream_passthrough: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/passthrough',
      _stream_readable: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/readable',
      _stream_writable: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/writable',
      _stream_transform: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/transform',
      timers: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/timers',
      console: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/console',
      vm: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/vm',
      zlib: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/zlib',
      tty: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/tty',
      domain: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/domain',
      // aliases for npm packages
      i18next: path.resolve('../React/node_modules/i18next'),
    },
  },
});
```

and here is my `vite.configClient.ts` file:

```
/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { createHtmlPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-html';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  root: './React',
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
    minify: true,
    cssMinify: true,
    lib: {
      entry: './index.tsx',
      name: 'React',
      fileName: 'app',
    },
    outDir: '../wwwroot/dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
        inject({
          process: 'process',
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    createHtmlPlugin(),
    react({
      include: '**/*.{jsx,tsx}',
      babel: {
        plugins: [
          [
            'babel-plugin-styled-components',
            {
              displayName: true,
              fileName: false,
            }
          ]
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-router-dom': path.resolve('../React/node_modules/react-router-dom'),
      'react-router': path.resolve('../React/node_modules/react-router'),
      react: path.resolve('../React/node_modules/react'),
      i18next: path.resolve('../React/node_modules/i18next'),
      'styled-components': path.resolve('../React/node_modules/styled-components'),
      'react-i18next': path.resolve('../React/node_modules/react-i18next'),
      'style-loader': path.resolve('../React/node_modules/style-loader'),
      grommet: path.resolve('../React/node_modules/grommet'),
      '@types/react': path.resolve('../React/node_modules/@types/react'),
      '@types/react-dom': path.resolve('../React/node_modules/@types/react-dom'),
      'react-toastify': path.resolve('../React/node_modules/react-toastify'),
    },
  },
});
```

Do you have any idea about having both builds consistent in styles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After removing old webpack and babel packages and config, build works fine in localhost (Windows), but error persists in Docker... do you have an idea about this?